# Catch-all-search, dynamic SQL?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I asked a question yesterday about a procedure we're trying to re-write/optimize in our application.  It's off of a search form with a bunch of criteria the user can specify.  40 parameters, 3 of which are long strings of Guids that I am passing into a UDF that returns a Table variable, all 3 of which we `JOIN` into our main `FROM` statement.

We did much of this query using Dynamic SQL, one of the main reasons we're re-writing the whole thing is because it's Dynamic SQL.  Everything I ever read about Dynamic SQL is bad, especially for execution plans and optimization.  Then I start coming across articles like these two....

[Sometimes the Simplest Solution isn't the Best Solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2009/05/03/sometimes-the-simplest-solution-isn-t-the-best-solution-the-all-in-one-search-query.aspx)

[Erland Sommarskog - Dynamic SQL Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html)

I've always though Dynamic SQL was bad for security and optimization, we've tried removing it form our system wherever possible.  Now we're restructuring the most executed query in our system (main search query) and we thought stripping all the Dynamic SQL was going to help.

Basically replacing

```
IF(@Param1 IS NULL)
   @SQLString = @SQLString + " AND FieldX = @Param1"
...execute the @SQLString
```

with one large SQL block that has

```
WHERE (@Param1 IS NOT NULL AND FieldX = @Param1)
```

Reading those two articles it seems like this is going to work against me.  I can't use `RECOMPILE` because we're in 2k5 still and even if we could this stored procedure is very high-use.  Do I really want to write this Query in Dynamic SQL?  How can it be faster if no execution plans can be stored?

Comment: Query hint `RECOMPILE` is [available in 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). Query plans for dynamic queries are cached also.

Comment: How can a query plan be cached when the query structure changes each time it is run?  Variables that don't exist aren't included in the WHERE clause at all and one call can be radically different than the other.

Comment: Also, I thought RECOMPILE was only for 2k8 and forward?

Comment: Have you considered evaluating which params are most common and maybe for the top several make custom sprocs?

Comment: @IshmaelStruan, regarding recompile option plase see link in my first comment. Regarding the dynamic queries: assume we execute dynamic query (#1)=`select name from [table] where id = @id`(@id=1) then another (#2)=`select name from [table] where id = @id and date > @date`(@some_id, @some_date), in this case, yes, query plan may be different, but if then again #1(@id=2) there is a good chance that cache hit will happen.